# CakePHP Tutorial Error: The request to /users did not apply any authorization checks

Tags: cakephp

I'm getting the error:

`The request to /users did not apply any authorization checks.`

When I try to run `http://localhost:8765/users`

I thought I followed the tutorial step by step correctly, but I most likely missed something somewhere. What's a good way to start debugging this error?

My UsersController.php file looks like this:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

/**
 * Users Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\UsersTable $Users
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\User[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface paginate($object = null, array $settings = [])
 */
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    
    public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        // Configure the login action to not require authentication, preventing
        // the infinite redirect loop issue
        $this->Authentication->addUnauthenticatedActions(['login', 'add']);
    }
    
    public function login()
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['get', 'post']);
        $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
        // regardless of POST or GET, redirect if user is logged in
        if ($result->isValid()) {
            // redirect to /articles after login success
            $redirect = $this->request->getQuery('redirect', [
                'controller' => 'Articles',
                'action' => 'index',
            ]);

            return $this->redirect($redirect);
        }
        // display error if user submitted and authentication failed
        if ($this->request->is('post') && !$result->isValid()) {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password'));
        }
        
        $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
    }
    
    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Renders view
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = $this->paginate($this->Users);
        $this->set(compact('users'));
    }

    /**
     * View method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Renders view
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Articles'],
        ]);

        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Add method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
        $user = $this->Users->newEmptyEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Edit method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => [],
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Redirects to index.
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $user = $this->Users->get($id);
        if ($this->Users->delete($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
    
    // in src/Controller/UsersController.php
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
        $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
        // regardless of POST or GET, redirect if user is logged in
        if ($result->isValid()) {
            $this->Authentication->logout();
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
        }
    }
}
```

And my Application.php like this:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

/**
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (https://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link      https://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since     3.3.0
 * @license   https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */
namespace App;

use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Core\ContainerInterface;
use Cake\Core\Exception\MissingPluginException;
use Cake\Datasource\FactoryLocator;
use Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware;
use Cake\Http\BaseApplication;
use Cake\Http\Middleware\BodyParserMiddleware;
use Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware;
use Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue;
use Cake\ORM\Locator\TableLocator;
use Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware;
use Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware;

// Authentication
use Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Authentication\AuthenticationServiceInterface;
use Authentication\AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface;
use Authentication\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

// Authorization
use Authorization\AuthorizationService;
use Authorization\AuthorizationServiceInterface;
use Authorization\AuthorizationServiceProviderInterface;
use Authorization\Middleware\AuthorizationMiddleware;
use Authorization\Policy\OrmResolver;

/**
 * Application setup class.
 *
 * This defines the bootstrapping logic and middleware layers you
 * want to use in your application.
 */
class Application extends BaseApplication implements AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface, AuthorizationServiceProviderInterface {
    /**
     * Load all the application configuration and bootstrap logic.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function bootstrap(): void
    {
        // Call parent to load bootstrap from files.
        parent::bootstrap();

        if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
            $this->bootstrapCli();
        } else {
            FactoryLocator::add(
                'Table',
                (new TableLocator())->allowFallbackClass(false)
            );
        }

        /*
         * Only try to load DebugKit in development mode
         * Debug Kit should not be installed on a production system
         */
        if (Configure::read('debug')) {
            $this->addPlugin('DebugKit');
        }
        
        $this->addPlugin('Authorization');
        
        // Load more plugins here
    }

    /**
     * Setup the middleware queue your application will use.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue $middlewareQueue The middleware queue to setup.
     * @return \Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue The updated middleware queue.
     */
    public function middleware(MiddlewareQueue $middlewareQueue): MiddlewareQueue
    {
        $middlewareQueue
            // Catch any exceptions in the lower layers,
            // and make an error page/response
            ->add(new ErrorHandlerMiddleware(Configure::read('Error')))

            // Handle plugin/theme assets like CakePHP normally does.
            ->add(new AssetMiddleware([
                'cacheTime' => Configure::read('Asset.cacheTime'),
            ]))

            // Add routing middleware.
            // If you have a large number of routes connected, turning on routes
            // caching in production could improve performance. For that when
            // creating the middleware instance specify the cache config name by
            // using it's second constructor argument:
            // `new RoutingMiddleware($this, '_cake_routes_')`
            ->add(new RoutingMiddleware($this))
            ->add(new AuthenticationMiddleware($this))
            ->add(new AuthorizationMiddleware($this))

            // Parse various types of encoded request bodies so that they are
            // available as array through $request->getData()
            // https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/middleware.html#body-parser-middleware
            ->add(new BodyParserMiddleware())

            // Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Protection Middleware
            // https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/middleware.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-middleware
            ->add(new CsrfProtectionMiddleware([
                'httponly' => true,
            ]));

        return $middlewareQueue;
    }

    public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthenticationServiceInterface
    {
        $authenticationService = new AuthenticationService([
            'unauthenticatedRedirect' => Router::url('/users/login'),
            'queryParam' => 'redirect',
        ]);

        // Load identifiers, ensure we check email and password fields
        $authenticationService->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password',
            ]
        ]);

        // Load the authenticators, you want session first
        $authenticationService->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
        // Configure form data check to pick email and password
        $authenticationService->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password',
            ],
            'loginUrl' => Router::url('/users/login'),
        ]);

        return $authenticationService;
    }

    /**
     * Register application container services.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Core\ContainerInterface $container The Container to update.
     * @return void
     * @link https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/dependency-injection.html#dependency-injection
     */
    public function services(ContainerInterface $container): void
    {
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrapping for CLI application.
     *
     * That is when running commands.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function bootstrapCli(): void
    {
        try {
            $this->addPlugin('Bake');
        } catch (MissingPluginException $e) {
            // Do not halt if the plugin is missing
        }

        $this->addPlugin('Migrations');

        // Load more plugins here
    }
    
    public function getAuthorizationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthorizationServiceInterface
    {
        $resolver = new OrmResolver();

        return new AuthorizationService($resolver);
    }
}
```

What am I failing to see? Thanks!

Comment: Just as the error message says, your users `index` function has not included a call to either `$this->Authorization->authorize` or `$this->Authorization->skipAuthorization`.

Answer (score 3):

Add skip authorization to your index method in atricles & users controller

$this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();